# Can not avoid duplicate data while fetching from database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have one issue.I can not avoid the duplicate data while retrieving from database using PHP and MySQL.I am explaining my code below.

```
   <?php
require_once '../../include/dbconfig.php'; 
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$colg_id=$request->colg_id;
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT DISTINCT dept_id  from db_unit_plan where clg_id='".$colg_id."'  ");
if($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //$dept_id = $row[dept_id]; 
    //$result = mysqli_query($connect, "select *  from db_department where colg_id='".$colg_id."' and dept_id='".$dept_id."'  ");
    $data = array();
    while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

print json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Here in the `db_unit_plan` table  many rows have same dept_id.Here i need to avoid the duplicate data.Please help me.

Comment: Can you show us what results you get, and what results you want to get?

Comment: Suppose i have 3 `dept_id in the colg_id=32` ,and those 3 are diffrent.It is fetching 2.if one is present it is fetching nothing.

Comment: I get it now, and I think mnv has the answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once '../../include/dbconfig.php'; 
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$colg_id=$request->colg_id;
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT DISTINCT dept_id FROM db_unit_plan where clg_id='".$colg_id."'  ");

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row['dept_id'];
}

print json_encode($data);
```

**EDIT**

If you need list of unique db_department in result:

```
<?php
require_once '../../include/dbconfig.php'; 
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$colg_id=$request->colg_id;
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT DISTINCT db_department.*  
    FROM db_department 
    JOIN db_unit_plan ON db_unit_plan.dept_id = db_department.dept_id
    WHERE db_unit_plan.clg_id='".$colg_id."'  ");

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: @ mnv: Yes your line is ok.But please see my post there are two comment line i have to execute also those.

Comment: you need list of db_department in result?

Comment: @ mnv :here i need first it will fetch dept_id from `db_unit_plan` table according to the colg_id with out any duplicate and then it will fetch all data  from `db_department` table using the given condition in an array. and finaly return it.

Comment: @ mnv : No,its returning blank array.